# how to specify response for specific request methods for API action in django

Tags: python, django, swagger, drf-spectacular

I have an API action in django which accepts GET and POST requests where each of them will have a distinct response schema. If a request is of method "GET" we will return a list, if it is "POST" we will return only the created entity...

```
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema

class SessionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    ...
    
    @extend_schema(
        parameters=[query_params["extra_query_param"]],
        responses={
            "GET": serializers.ExampleSerializer(many=True),
            "POST": serializers.ExampleSerializer(many=False),
        },
    )
    @action(
        detail=True,
        url_path="example",
        methods=["GET", "POST"],
        filter_backends=[],
    )
    def example(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        match request.method:
            case "GET":
                queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(session_pk_id=pk)
                page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
                serializer = get_serializer(page, many=True)
                return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
            case "POST":
                serializer = get_serializer(data=request.data, many=False
                )
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response(
                        serializer.data,
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    )
                else:
                    return Response(
                        serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                    )
            case _:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

The problem is that now I am not sure how to define this rule so that the swagger auto-schema will detect and present as such.

How can I explicitly state that a response schema or serializer belongs to a specific request method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django Rest framework generic views and viewsets you have to specify the serializer in one of two ways:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself

1. Define the `serializer_class` attribute
2. Override the `get_serializer_class` method

Overriding the `get_serializer_class` method is useful when the serializer depends on the request, just like your case. Drf_spectacular introspection [relies on this functionality](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-1-queryset-and-serializer-class). In your example you are defining the serializer within your custom action so drf_spectacular has no way of knowing which serializer is expected for each request type.

So, you simply need to move your logic to `get_serializer_class` and drf_spectacular will be able to recognize it properly:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    match self.request.method:
        case "POST":
            return FirstSerializerClass
        case "GET":
            return SecondSerializerClass

    raise ApiException(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, reason="Method {} not allowed.".format(self.request.method))
```

The above code assumes default error handling where ApiExceptions are automatically converted to HTTP responses.

UPDATE:
Don't forget to use `self.get_serializer_class()` or the shortcut method `self.get_serializer()` within your action to keep the code DRY.